# Docker compose issue with pgAdmin

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file.

But I am unable to connect to pgAdmin from the browser. I don't understand the issue as if I send data from postman then it gets saved to pgAdmin app which is on my local machine But when I visit localhost://5050/browser/ then that table does not appear in the browser.

```
version: '1'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      app_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.11
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'pg_isready -U postgres']
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-'email'}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-'password'}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'

    ports:
      - '${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80'
    networks:
      - app_network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  app_network:
    external: true
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

The tables from my pgAdmin app.

[image]

The tables from the localhost:5050/browser/ link.
[image]

I have correctly set the connection for pgAdmin in browser.

Comment: So you can connect to pgAdmin from both a "pgAdmin app" and the browser but they show different tables? Do you recognize both the lists of tables? Are they both part of your application?

Comment: @JKL Yes, they both are part of my application. I have total 23 tables.

Comment: Sounds like a user issue where you sign in with different users and both have rights to see different tables. When you go to pgAdmin in browser you first need to login, after that, did you create a connection to your postgres server? Or is your server visible immediately?

Comment: @JKL I have created connection manually.